# Google Maps API Directions Service: find midpoint based on time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build a small app that finds the midpoint of a route and provides information about the area. I'm using Mike Williams' [epoly](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm) library to get the midpoint based on distance, which is very easy to accomplish.  However, I'd like to find the midpoint based on time as it seems like a more accurate, or at least helpful, way to represent the midpoint.

Currently my approach uses binary search to find coordinates along the route that are within a 1/n difference of 0.5 * total time.  However, this seems like a terrible approach because it has to repeatedly call the `Directions Service` until an acceptable coordinate is found.

I've looked through the docs and S.O. extensively but I've been unable to find a better approach.  Is there something out there that I'm overlooking?  Any advice would be great appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to get close by summing the duration of the segments of the route (rather than adding the extra overhead/costs of hitting the API multiple times)

Comment: I thought about this as well since segments are the smallest unit returned with a time value.  However, segments can be any distance so most of the time this wouldn't work.  Say to get from A to B you took train 1 for 45 minutes and then train 2 for 15 minutes.  You'd still have to find a point that's close to the middle of the first segment.